# Editor Keyboard Maps not specific

Tags: interface

Why is the blender editor menu keyboard map not specific
Image Editor and UV Editor are both Shift f10
and trying to change the keymap failed.
I don't understand why each editor doesn't have its own keymap.

[image: blender editor menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same, because it's the same editor; only presenting a different interface.  If you hit <kbd>F10</kbd> multiple times, it will cycle between the two interfaces.

The same thing happens with <kbd>F3</kbd>, the node editor and several others.  Many of Blender's editors are instances of a shared editor that just presents different interfaces depending on what it is used to edit.

Comment: Thanks, Marty, you come to the rescue again. Sad to hear that multiple click will not work with in PME (Pie Menu Editor)